# Laravel whereBetween function not working to my query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My table column data type is Date and the date format is "2022-05-25". My Query is

```
$customers = Customer::with(['outstanding_invoices', 'address', 'rep'])
            ->where('status', 'A');

$from_date = Carbon::parse($from_date)->format('Y-m-d');
$end_date = Carbon::parse($end_date)->format('Y-m-d');

$customers->whereHas('outstanding_invoices', function ($query) use ($from_date, $end_date) {
                $query->whereBetween('invoice_date', [$from_date, $end_date]); //* 1
                // $query->where('invoice_date', '>=', $from_date); //* 2
                // $query->where('invoice_date', '<=', $end_date);
                // $query->whereDate('invoice_date', '>=', $from_date); //* 3
                // $query->whereDate('invoice_date', '<=', $end_date);
            });
$customers = $customers->get();
```

I have tried below three commented options but did not filter to the dates.

Comment: Do not format the string, pass the carbon instances to whereBetween

Comment: Try debugging the query by dumping it with `$customers->toSql();` and see what it does. You're including the outstanding_invoices relation twice, that might be a problem. `with(...)` and `whereHas(...)`